# How to connect from a Linux machine to an Ubuntu machine on internal network only?

Tags: remote-desktop, remote-access

I want to be able to access one of my Ubuntu computers from a Linux computer, from within my Home Network, but for it to be impossible to do so from outside.

What would be the best way to go about this?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

Secure Shell is one choice that is fairly easy. SSH can be accessed from the WAN by port forwarding in your router settings.

Remote Desktop is easy and available natively on Ubuntu machines. The instructions to set it up can be found at the following page.
http://www.makeuseof.com/tag/ubuntu-remote-desktop-builtin-vnc-compatible-dead-easy/

You need to go into Desktop Sharing Preferences and allow others to view your Desktop and allow other users to control your desktop. You can set a password under security if you so desire.

After you find the IP address you can use Remmina Remote Desktop client to access it from that machine. You can use ifconfig to determine the IP address. When you open Remmina it should look similar to the picture below. However it will auto-populate with RDP, you will need to change this to VNC.[image]

Remote Desktop can also be accessed from WAN by forwarding the port, but if this isn't setup you won't have access. One thing to check is to make sure that you are using VNC not RDP as your protocol to connect.

On the machine you want to connect from you will need to make sure that Remmina is installed and properly.
In Ubuntu/Debian:

```
sudo apt-get install remmina remmina-plugin-*
```

In Centos/RHEL:

```
yum install remmina remmina-plugin-*
```

In Fedora:

```
sudo dnf copr enable hubbitus/remmina-next
sudo dnf upgrade --refresh 'remmina*' 'freerdp*'
```

Comment: Will this prevent connections from outside the network, or will that still be possible?

Comment: With SSH you would have to go into your router settings and allow connection from outside. I don't believe that Reminna allows any access from outside the LAN. Scratch that, it can as well but like SSH it has to be set up in your router settings.

Comment: When using Remmina, it keeps saying Unable to Connect, even though I think I am doing everything correct. I have all the settings like in the link you sent, but it won't work.

Comment: @Tyler  try `gsettings set org.gnome.Vino require-encryption false` on the machine with Remote Desktop turned on, then connect from the other machine

Comment: @nullmeta That didn't change anything.

Comment: @Tyler have you tried using the default built-in Remote Desktop viewer?

Comment: @nullmeta I may have what is it called? Also, is it only built into Ubuntu, because I realized I am trying to connect from a Linux, not Ubuntu?

Comment: What system are you trying to connect from? What is your security setting?

Comment: Are you using VNC not RDP?

Comment: @Robby1212 I am using Remote Desktop Settings on the Ubuntu machine that I want to connect to (like in the link you sent). I am trying to connect from a Linux machine using Remmina (like in the link you sent).

Comment: And are you using VNC protocol?

Comment: @Robby1212 I was using RDP, how do I switch? I don't remember it being an option.

Comment: In the picture above, you see RDP on the left? That is a drop down menu and you should be able to chose VNC from that list.

Comment: @Robby1212 I believe there are only two options for me, RDP & SSH.

Comment: Sounds like you might be missing some of the Remmina protocols/functionality. Have you made sure that you have all of Remmina plugins installed?
This will make sure you have all of the needed plugins on Ubuntu/Debian.
    sudo apt-get install remmina remmina-plugin-*
Centos/RHEL
    yum install remmina remmina-plugin-*
Fedora
    sudo dnf copr enable hubbitus/remmina-next
    sudo dnf upgrade --refresh 'remmina*' 'freerdp*'

Comment: Now it just continually says "Connecting..." but never connects.

Comment: How is your firewall setup?

Comment: The claim that SSH only allows for CLI access is what made me downvote this answer. This is a rather outrageous claim, limiting the view on SSH - an extremely versatile protocol - to the capabilities of one of its clients (`ssh`).

Comment: @0xC0000022L  Happy now?

Comment: @Robby1212 it's not about whether I'm happy. If you were happy with the previous revision, that's fine, too. I just don't think that it gives any future visitor the sort of information they should get, because it limits the view to one client, but the wording suggested it was a limitation of the protocol. I just wanted to provide feedback (including why the downvote) and saw no reason _not_ to provide it in this case.

Comment: @0xC0000022L Thank you for clarifying that and I apologize for the passive aggressiveness of my response. Shame on me for reacting in such a fashion. That should teach me to not respond to messages when I first wake up in the morning. I am far to grumpy to be thinking concisely! I did write this answer a few years back when my grasp on the capabilities of SSH was not what it is now. Thank you for helping future proof my answer.

Comment: @Robby1212 no worries, been there, done that. You can probably still find evidence here on StackExchange all over the place.

Answer (score 0):

If you are familiar with terminal, you can use `ssh`. Simply install on the **machine you want to control** package `openssh-server`.

On your local machine open terminal and type `ssh login@internal_ip_of_your_remote_machine`. Some networks even work with hostname (`login@hostname.local`).

If you want to skip logging in all the time, you can create and copy your public authentification key:

`ssh-keygen` - if you have already not generated your ssh key (you can confirm everything)

`ssh-copy-id login@remote_machine` and enter remote password.
From now on you can login from your computer without password query.